# Python - How to plot a 3D array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a simple way to plot a 3D array (i.e., an array with shape `(a,b,c)`) on Python like the one in the picture?

`plot_surface, scatter` from matplotlib, and other packages like `pyx` don't satisfy my requirements as they want explicit `(x,y,z)` arrays, and I think looping over the 3D array is inefficient.

[image: 3D stellar atmosphere]

(from http://rsaa.anu.edu.au/study/potential-projects/stellar-magnetic-fields-and-stellar-spectra)

Comment: I could imagine the picture being produced with Mayavi.